# Google sheets - return earliest date across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I think there might be a simple solution to this, but I need help.

I have one google sheet with four sub-sheets.

Sheet1 list several products, e.g:

Product1

Product2

Sheet2, 3 and 4 lists identical products, but with different delivery dates.
Eg:

Product1   10.09.2020

Product2   13.09.2020

I want a formula for Sheet1 to gather the earliest delivery date across all of the sub-sheets.

If sheet2 has Product 1 with delivery date 14.09.2020, and sheet3 has the earliest date at 07.09.2020-
then I want the formula to Return 07.09.2020 in the column next to product1 in sheet1.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O5yZBrkLgjdQOIhjDNmUtoQKU511HLgbv_VzO2AmqNI/edit?usp=sharing

```
=MIN({Sheet2!A:A,Sheet3!A:A,Sheet4!A:A,Sheet5!A:A})
```

Just add any date ranges inside the curly brackets separated by a comma.